# SQLite Compare two columns

Tags: sqlite, insert

I am creating a database for my Psych class and I am scoring a personality profile. I need to compare two test items and, if they match a condition, then copy into a separate table.

Example (pseudocode is between \)Sqlite3

```
INSERT INTO Scale
SELECT* FROM Questions
WHERE \\if Question 1 IS 'TRUE' AND Question 3 IS 'FALSE' THEN Copy this Question
and its response into the Scale table\\;
```

I have about 100 other questions that work like this. Sample format goes like this:

```
IF FirstQuestion IS value AND SecondQuestion IS value THEN 
Copy both questions into the Scale TABLE.
```

### ---------- EDITED AFTER FIRST RESPONSE! EDITS FOLLOW-------------

Here is my TestItems table:

````````````````````````````````````````````````````
ItemID |      ItemQuestion       | ItemResponse
```````````````````````````````````````````````````
   1   |    Is the sky blue?     |    TRUE
   2   |    Are you a person?    |    TRUE
   3   |    2 Plus 2 Equals Five |    FALSE
````````````````````````````````````````````````````

What I want to do: If Question 1 is TRUE AND Question 3 is FALSE, then insert BOTH questions into the table 'Scale' (which is setup like TestItems). I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO Scale
SELECT * FROM TestItems
WHERE ((ItemID=1) AND (ItemResponse='TRUE')) 
AND ((ItemID=3) AND (ItemResponse='FALSE'));
```

HOWEVER: The above INSERT copies neither.
The Resulting 'Scale' table should look like this:

````````````````````````````````````````````````````
ItemID |      ItemQuestion       | ItemResponse
```````````````````````````````````````````````````
   1   |    Is the sky blue?     |    TRUE
   3   |    2 Plus 2 Equals Five |    FALSE
````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your query. You're just there:

```
INSERT INTO Scale
SELECT * FROM Questions
WHERE `Question 1` = 1 AND `Question 3` = 0;
```

Here 1 and 0 are values (in your first case, true and false). First of all you should ensure there are fields `Question 1` and `Question 3` in your `Questions` table. Secondly the column count as well as data types of `Scale` table should match `Questions` table. Otherwise you will have to do selectively choose the fields in your `SELECT` query.

**Edit:** To respond to your edit, I am not seeing an elegant solution. You could do this:

```
INSERT INTO Scale
SELECT * FROM TestItems WHERE ItemID = 1 AND ItemResponse = 'TRUE'
UNION
SELECT * FROM TestItems WHERE ItemID = 3 AND ItemResponse = 'FALSE'
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
                             SELECT 1 FROM TestItems WHERE ItemID = 1 AND ItemResponse = 'TRUE'
                             UNION
                             SELECT * FROM TestItems WHERE ItemID = 3 AND ItemResponse = 'FALSE'
                            ) AS t) >= 2
```

Your insert did not work because `ItemID` cant be both 1 and 3 at the same time. My solution gets the required records to be inserted into `Scale` table, but verifies both the record exists by checking the count. Additionally you could **(should)** do as below since this can be marginally more efficient (the above SQL was to clearly show the logic being used):

```
INSERT INTO Scale
SELECT * FROM TestItems WHERE ItemID = 1 AND ItemResponse = 'TRUE'
UNION
SELECT * FROM TestItems WHERE ItemID = 3 AND ItemResponse = 'FALSE'
WHERE (
       SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM   TestItems 
       WHERE  ItemID = 1 AND ItemResponse = 'TRUE' 
           OR ItemID = 3 AND ItemResponse = 'FALSE'
      ) >= 2
```

Comment: Actually I still can't get it to work. Lemme show you what Ive done, what I've tried, and what I WANT to do.

Comment: I've edited the question above to further clarify what I mean.